# How do I encrypt files with Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cryptography, cryptojs

I am currently working on a encryption tool and wanted to implement a way to encrypt files. Is there a native way to do this or is there a package that would handle this sort of feature.

Comment: There is a handy NPM package called cryptify (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptify) should do the job.

Comment: @EX-C Thanks I'll try it out

Comment: Horrid. No description of the password based key derivation function (PBKDF) to be used, no way to indicate the number of iterations or work factor. No protocol description. The use of any or all ciphers without a sensible default such as an authenticated cipher. Use at your own peril. Maybe something based on NaCL is a better option.